# How to deal with loop in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have a question some general because I have problems with. I'll take an example to show you, I have an application with a loop to connect two accounts.

```
for each{
   Login informations
   Make connect
}
```

But in this situation, the first loop are going to make the connect and going immediately to the second loop with new login informations. So the second account is the only one connected.

Edit : http://pastebin.com/zuWSzxBX

Thanks per advance!

PokeRwOw

Comment: and do you have any particular code which is nit working?

Comment: Just don't use `i` in asynch callbacks, make a closure.

Comment: Like `(function(row){/*use row here*/})(rows[i]);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You use 'expired' `i` in your asynchronous callbacks.
It's often error.

Write a function to process each row and call it in each loop iteration:

```
function processRow(row){
  // process row
}
for(var i in rows) processRow(rows[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks you, you solved my problem ! Do you have any documentations about this ? I never saw this before...

Comment: It's just javascript. What docs do you want? About visibility scopes? Event loop? Asynchronous workflow?